# Wordpress Theme Includes Error in td_remote and td_video page

Tags: wordpress, plugins

My wordpress version is 4.9.4 i am using a paid theme but after install that i have faced several error here is the description :

Warning: Illegal string offset 'test_time' in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\Newsmag\includes\wp_booster\td_remote_http.php on line 93

Warning: Illegal string offset 'test_status' in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\Newsmag\includes\wp_booster\td_remote_http.php on line 95

Warning: Illegal string offset 'youtube_ids' in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\Newsmag\includes\wp_booster\td_video_playlist_render.php on line 72

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVPJU.png)

Comment: Do you have all plugins disabled?

Comment: Raise this issue with the theme developer.